# Does a copy of your commander count as your "Commander"?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

The new Commander edition introduces a keyword *Lieutenant*, which gives bonuses as long as you control your commander.
Is that bonus still granted if you control a clone of your commander only?
And what happens if you steal an opponent's same named commander?

Comment: Tiny nitpickery: Lieutenant isn't a keyword, it's actually an _ability word_.  Think of it as a form of reminder text: the word 'Lieutenant' doesn't carry any rules weight, it just lets you know that something is going on when you control your commander.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, only your own original commander counts.**

Generally, if the Lieutenant ability refers to *your* Commander, then the opponent's Commander would not count, since it's not yours, even if it has the same name. Also, a clone of your Commander would not count, because the Commander-ness of a card cannot be copied.

> 903.3. Each deck has a legendary creature card designated as its commander. **This designation is not a characteristic of the object represented by the card; rather, it is an attribute of the card itself.** The card retains this designation even when it changes zones.
>
> *Example: A commander that’s been turned face down (due to Ixidron’s effect, for example) is still a commander. A commander that’s copying another card (due to Cytoshape’s effect, for example) is still a commander.* ***A permanent that’s copying a commander (such as a Body Double, for example, copying a commander in a player’s graveyard) is not a commander.***

Comment: Thanks. Lieutenant is going to be introduced with the next commander edition, see e.g. [here](http://mythicspoiler.com/).